Performance issue with Jetpack Compose's Google Maps
I have been trying to create a google maps screen, with clustering, that based on a condition, will switch between markers (positioning and image). When switching, performance is TERRIBLE. It literally lags for 2 seconds, and any click makes it crash. Any help?
val items1 by viewModel!!.items1.collectAsState()
val items2 by viewModel!!.items2.collectAsState()
val selectedType by viewModel!!.selectedType.collectAsState()

...


GoogleMap(
    modifier = Modifier
        .weight(weight = 1f),
    properties = MapProperties(mapType = MapType.NORMAL),
    uiSettings = MapUiSettings(
         zoomControlsEnabled = false,
         mapToolbarEnabled = false,
         tiltGesturesEnabled = false,
         myLocationButtonEnabled = false
    ),
    cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
    onMapLoaded = { }
) {
    Clustering(
         items = if (selectedType == ProjectType.TYPE_1) items1 else items2,
         clusterItemContent = { item ->
               val isSelected = (item == selectedItem)

               val imageRes = when {
                    selectedType == ProjectType.TYPE_1 && isSelected -> R.drawable.ic_drawable_1
                    selectedType == ProjectType.TYPE_1 -> R.drawable.ic_drawable_2
                    selectedType == ProjectType.TYPE_2 && isSelected -> R.drawable.ic_drawable_3
                    selectedType == ProjectType.TYPE_2 -> R.drawable.ic_drawable_4
                    else -> R.drawable.ic_drawable_5
              }

              Image(
                  modifier = Modifier.size(36.dp),
                  painter = painterResource(id = imageRes),
                  contentDescription = null,
              )
       },
       onClusterItemClick = { item ->
              coroutineScope.launch {
              ...
              }

              true
       }
  )

